# "Path for saving emails is invalid: None" in django

Tags: python, django, email

my project was running correctly but after that I made few apps I start my work on previous app but I'm trying to send email this time I'm getting this error and I'm not able to understand what's the problem, I tried to get email and console and it's working but when I use

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
```

I get this error, can someone help to figure it out what's the problem [image: this is image of error link]

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND', default='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST', cast=Csv())
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
```

This is what I'm using in my settings

Comment: Please share your email code in settings.py file.

Comment: @MandeepThakur done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend` instead of  `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` in your **settings.py**. Or you could be using `get_connection` method to use a backend when sending an email like this:

```
connection = get_connection(backend="django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend")
# some other code
connection.send_messages(messages)
```

If you do, then make sure to set `EMAIL_FILE_PATH` in **settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/app-messages'  # Proper path should be given here
```

More details can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#file-backend

Comment: no I'm using smtp backend and I don't need file backend

Comment: You should check your `.ini` or `.env` file with EMAIL_BACKEND if it has `django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend`, because the error you are getting is definitely related to `django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend`

Comment: Well, in your initial question, you didn't provide any code, maybe that is why. But maybe, I don't know.